# Correct form of closing PHP code, free result and close connection

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, row, echo

I am just learning so I would like to ask about the correct way of closing IF in PHP code:

Here is example one at the end of page

```
<?php

   session_start();
   $identification = $_SESSION['session_name'];
   include 'inc/database.php';
   $query = "SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `username` = '$identification' LIMIT 1";
   $result = mysqli_query($database, $query);
   $user_info = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
   $user_level = $user_info["privs"];
   if ($user_level=='ADMIN'){} 
   else {
     header('Location: security.php?error=missing correct privileges. user is not admin');
     exit();
?>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Zona de Pruebas</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      Username: <?php echo $user_info['username']?>, can be here because is admin</div>
   </body>
</html>
<?php
   }
   mysqli_free_result($result);
   mysqli_close($database);
?>
```

Here is example two before HTML body

```
<?php

   session_start();
   $identification = $_SESSION['session_name'];
   include 'inc/database.php';
   $query = "SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `username` = '$identification' LIMIT 1";
   $result = mysqli_query($database, $query);
   $user_info = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
   $user_level = $user_info["privs"];
   if ($user_level=='ADMIN'){} 
   else {
     header('Location: security.php?error=missing correct privileges. user is not admin');
     exit();
   }
   mysqli_free_result($result);
   mysqli_close($database);
?>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Zona de Pruebas</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      Username: <?php echo $user_info['username']?>, can be here because is admin</div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Whats is the correct way? At the top or at the end? Is a good idea to use the free result and close database connection? Is this the correct way? I am trying to learn.

Comment: I'd recommand you to use `if ($user_level!='ADMIN'){ *Insert your else code* }` for a better readability

Comment: Can you show me a example for dummys please?

Comment: The idea is that checking user level if user is admin we do nothing if not we kick the user (redirect) to other page

Comment: just don't use some if statement without anything inside of it! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
<?php

session_start();
$identification = $_SESSION['session_name'];
include 'inc/database.php';
$query = "SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `username` = '" . $identification . "' LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($database, $query);
$user_info = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

//Close your connection here, you dont need it anymore.

mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_close($database);

$user_level = $user_info["privs"];

//If $user_level is not equal to 'ADMIN'
if ($user_level != 'ADMIN'){

  header('Location: security.php?error=missing correct privileges. user is not admin');
  exit();
  ?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Zona de Pruebas</title>
</head>
<body>
Username: <?php echo $user_info['username']?>, can be here because is admin</div>
</body>
</html>
//End the If
<?php } ?>
```

I would recommend putting your html code inside a php file and call it like so:

```
include('view/myView.php');
```

All your variables will be passed to this separate file.

so it could look like this:

```
<?php

    session_start();
    $identification = $_SESSION['session_name'];
    include 'inc/database.php';
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `username` = '" . $identification ."' LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($database, $query);
    $user_info = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    //Close your connection here, you dont need it anymore.

    mysqli_free_result($result);
    mysqli_close($database);

    $user_level = $user_info["privs"];

    //If $user_level is not equal to 'ADMIN'
    if ($user_level != 'ADMIN'){

      header('Location: security.php?error=missing correct privileges. user is not admin');
      exit();
      include('view/myView.php');
    //End the If
    } ?>
```

myView.php

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Zona de Pruebas</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    Username: <?php echo $user_info['username']?>, can be here because is admin</div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Which looks alot cleaner. Or is the HTML inside security.php ? if so then you dont need the include.

Comment: Thanks man I really like your first part without the myview is what I need. Just a small question. The mysqli_free_result($result); and 
mysqli_close($database); is correct there or it must be after  $user_level = $user_info["privs"]; ?

Comment: its correct there. You already have $user_info defined and populated and you dont need the connection anymore.